# Trying to check a text box fails

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a check for a text box written in HTML, but it keeps throwing exceptions :

```
public partial class First : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = "";
        username = Request.QueryString["UsernameBox"];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (username[i] < 'a' && username[i] > 'z' && username[i] < 'A' && username[i] > 'Z')
            {
                Response.Write("NO");
                break;
            }
            else
                Response.Redirect("Second.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

The errors :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 15:         for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
>
> Line 16:         {
>
> Line 17:             **if (username[i] < 'a' && username[i] > 'z' && username[i] < 'A' && username[i] > 'Z')**
>
> Line 18:             {
>
> Line 19:                 Response.Write("NO");
>
> Source File: c:\Users\User\Desktop\SE Assignment\First.aspx.cs    Line: 17

Comment: `Request.QueryString["UsernameBox"]` returns `null`.

Comment: Do a quick check for null as @CodeCaster suggests. if (Request.QueryString["UsernameBox"] != null) { username = Request.QueryString["UsernameBox"]; //run the loop }